# What is the name of the monadic "versions" of fmap?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor

Having a background in powershell scripting i first thought it natural to think of function composition in a pipe kind of way. That means the syntax for composition should be `fun1 | fun2 | fun3` in a psudocode kind of way. (where `fun[i]` is the `i`'th function to apply in order). This order of functions is also what you find in haskell monadic binds. `fun1 >>= fun2 >>= fun3`.

But in other occasions in haskell, the order of functions is more math'y, such as `fun3 . fun2 . fun1`, or in the functorial setting `fmap fun3 . fmap fun2 . fmap fun1`.

I am very much aware that the functions have different signature in the two examples, but it puzzles me that the structure is reversed, still. My workaround is to sometimes define a function `mmap = flip (>>=)` such that I can write `mmap fun3 . mmap fun2 . mmap fun1`.

So to the question:

1. Is there a `mmap` already defined? What is is called?
2. Why if bind defined as an operator with arguments in an order that feels backwards?

Comment: Your `mmap` is, not surprisingly, `=<<`. Monadic bind is not analogous to function composition; it is more like function application.

Comment: Good point about application/composition chepner. I ended up switching to Kliesli composition (<=<) instead of reverse bind (=<<),

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a `mmap` already defined? What is is called?

[Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is your friend. The type signature of [`(>>=)`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28%3E%3E%3D%29) is:

```hs
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Hence, you're looking for a function with the type signature:

```hs
flip (>>=) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

This is in fact the [`=<<`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28%3D%3C%3C%29) function. Hence, you can write `fun3 =<< fun2 =<< fun1`.

> Why is bind defined as an operator with arguments in an order that feels backwards?

It's because monadic code looks a lot like imperative code. For example, consider the following:

```hs
permute2 :: [a] -> [[a]]
permute2 xs = do
    x  <- xs
    xs <- map return xs
    return (x:xs)
```

Without the syntactic sugar of `do` it would be written as:

```hs
permute2 :: [a] -> [[a]]
permute2 xs =
    xs >>= \x ->
    map return xs >>= \xs ->
    return (x:xs)
```

See the similarity? If we used `=<<` instead it would look like:

```hs
permute2 :: [a] -> [[a]]
permute2 xs = (\x -> (\xs -> return (x:xs)) =<< map return xs) =<< xs
```

Not very readable is it?